# Bootstrap fixed content pane

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a "clean" way to make a bootstrap standard 2-column layout with the sidebar (a list of items) long and scrollable and the main content area fixed? I would like to use the main content area to inject ajax content by intercepting the links on the left, so I would like it to stay always visible.

Comment: So you want to use default fluid layout http://goo.gl/jkyfJ. I just don't get it, why do you need it to be fixed. Add id to the right column, make your left column as long as you want and itercept events on sidebar with ajax to change contents of the right column.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but with this fluid when a user scrolls down, let's say the height of the browsers'window and makes a choice, the right column is empty because the content is at the top and I would like it to be fixed, always visible without scrolling back to the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `position: fixed` to your sidebar class, and style as you see fit. See an example with Bootstrap here: http://jsfiddle.net/eterpstra/nxrpu/1/

Comment: FYI; when the browser isn't that high, the left sidebar isn't visible anymore because you can't scroll...